# Transposing Multiple Columns With a Key Identifier Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I need to transpose multiple columns into one column, with an already existing column acting as key identifier. I would prefer to do this using pandas, but plain python will also be fine.

The table at hand looks like this

```
ID    Col1    Col2    Col3
01     'a'     'b'    'c'
02     'a'     'b'    'c'
03     'a'     'b'    'c'
```

The desired results should look like this:

```
ID    Col1
01     'a'
01     'b'
01     'c'
02     'a'
02     'b'
02     'c'
03     'a'
03     'b'
03     'c'
```

Thanks everyone <3

Answer (score 1):

You can simply stack the dataframe and rename the series

```
df.set_index('ID').stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True).rename('Col1').reset_index()
```

out:

```
    ID  Col1
0   1   'a'
1   1   'b'
2   1   'c'
3   2   'a'
4   2   'b'
5   2   'c'
6   3   'a'
7   3   'b'
8   3   'c'
```

Answer (score 0):

#### [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html) + [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Here's one way. Sorting is only necessary if the order of rows is relevant.

```
res = pd.melt(df, id_vars='ID', value_name=df.columns[1])\
        .drop('variable', 1).sort_values('ID').reset_index(drop=True)

print(res)

   ID Col1
0   1  'a'
1   1  'b'
2   1  'c'
3   2  'a'
4   2  'b'
5   2  'c'
6   3  'a'
7   3  'b'
8   3  'c'
```